# Logstash plugin kv - keys and values not getting read into Elastic

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

Small part of my CSV log:

```
TAGS
contentms:Drupal;contentms.ver:7.1.8;vuln:rce;cve:CVE-2018-0111;
cve:CVE-2014-0160;vuln:Heartbleed;
contentms.ver:4.1.6;contentms:WordPress;tag:backdoor
tag:energia;
```

Idea is that I know nothing of the keys and values other than the format

> key:value;key:value;key:value;key:value; etc

I just create an pattern with logstash plugin "kv"

```
kv {
        source => "TAGS"
        field_split => ";"
        value_split => ":"
        target => "TAGS"
    }
```

I've been trying to get my data into Elastic for Kibana and some of it goes through. But for example keys `contentms:` and `contentms.ver:` don't get read. Also keys that do - only one value is searchable in Kibana. For example key `cve:` is seen on mutliple lines mutliple times in my log with different values but only this value is indexed `cve:CVE-2014-0160` same problem for `tag:` and `vuln:` keys.

I've seen some similar problems and solutions with ruby, but any solutions with just kv? or change my log format around a bit?

Answer (score 0):

I can't test it right now, but notice that you have both "contentms" (a string) and "contentms.ver", which probably looks to elasticsearch like a nested field ([contentms][ver]), but "contentms" was already defined as a string, so you can't nest beneath it.

After the cvs filter, try renaming "contentms" to "[contentms][name]", which would then be a peer to "[contentms][ver]".

You'd need to start with a new index to create this new mapping.